# how can i add new routes when pressing a button in flutter?

Tags: flutter

i want to make an app where i'd be able to add text entries, you click a button and it navigates to another page that has a textfield, then after you save that page i want to be able to access it again later with the text intact when you click that same button, how could i do this?

i tried adding a route for every page dynamically and failed, i tried to think of a better logic, but i am unable to come up with a reasonable solution

additionally, i am new to this, so, what could be a better way to debug these problems other than writing here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.